# global variable incrementation inside function does not work properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, global-variables

n is declared as Global variable. Inside function I add one to it. As I click button it only adds one time, and globally shows n as 1, not adding anymore to it by each click. Want to know why?

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
n=0
def click():
    print(globals())
    global n
    n +=1
    print(n)
tk.Button(master=root, command=click)
root.mainloop()
```

So, in each click, (only in first click n as print(globals) shows 'n':0) n is printed as one

Comment: When I try to run this exact code, no button shows up. When I fix that error, the button works as expected. Every time I click the button `n` is incremented by one and the new value is printed.

Comment: b= tk(...) b.pack()

Comment: Comment out line 6  `print(globals())`.  It should  work now.